# SKBlendModeMultiply on PNG image with alpha

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I have an issue with SpriteKit. I have a `.png` that is a drop shadow for my character that is a `SKSpriteNode` image. When I set the mode to `SKBlendModeMultiply` it treats the alpha in the image as black, making the whole image a black square.

Does anyone know how to fix this issues? It even seems to happen when you also set particles in a `SKEmitterNode` to `SKBlendNodeMultiply` as well.

Comment: Have you checked the alpha is correct, I have been using images with alphas (rendered in MODO) with no problem at all. can you post one of the images you are using that is not working?

Comment: Please post the code you're using and a link to images you're working with. Otherwise we can't help you diagnose the problem because there isn't enough information here.

Comment: Well A very quick way to test it is make a new Sprite Kit Project. All I did is just add one line : 
"[sprite setBlendMode:SKBlendModeMultiply];" after SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];

Here is a pic of the whole method: http://screencast.com/t/DROYz43xBLI

And here is a pic of the results I'm getting http://screencast.com/t/3F66h3dUOE2

I change the background colour to white to better show the issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you are having is that your not using the correct blend mode, if your using an image with a built in alpha (like the Apple spaceship or my UFO below) you don't need to specify a blend mode as the default value of `[sprite setBlendMode:SKBlendModeAlpha];` is correct for an image with an embedded alpha.

**IMAGE USED**

[image: Image used]

Try removing the line [sprite setBlendMode:SKBlendModeMultiply]; in you code, or replace it with [sprite setBlendMode:SKBlendModeAlpha]; to get the correct result. Here is the code I used,

**CODE USED**

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        self.backgroundColor = [SKColor redColor];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"TEST_0001"];
        //[sprite setBlendMode:SKBlendModeAlpha]; // Default value

        sprite.position = location;
        SKAction *action = [SKAction rotateByAngle:M_PI duration:1];
        [sprite runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:action]];
        [self addChild:sprite];
    }
}
```

and a screen grad from the simulator showing the comp.

**SIMULATOR**

[image: Output on simulator]